# compare a list of strings on each character

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare the characters of each string in a list of strings to see which ones match a certain character. After I want to figure out what percentage of the characters in the list of strings match the given character.

So in the end I want a percentage for each character of each string.

This is what I could think of, but it does not work how I want it to

```
def GC_content_pos(reads_list):
    for read in reads_list:
        for position in range(len(read)):
            if read[position] == "G" or read[position] == "C":
                #do something
```

Comment: Please provide your input , desire output.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question you want to percentage of characters in a string that match `'G'` or `'C'`? In that case if you start with this list of strings

```
>>> reads_list = ['GC', 'GA', 'GABCDE']
```

You can use a list comprehension to count the number of letter matches for each string, then divide the count of matches with the length of the string

```
>>> [sum(1 for i in s if i in 'GC')/len(s) for s in reads_list]
[1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333]
```

Or multiply by 100 to get percentages

```
>>> [sum(1 for i in s if i in 'GC')/len(s)*100 for s in reads_list]
[100.0, 50.0, 33.33333333333333]
```

Answer (score 2):

For finding matches, using regex is more efficient than iterating through each character. This function will return the percentage of each string that is either `G` or `C`. You can modify it to get the percentages separately for `G` or `C` if that is the requirement.

```
import re

def str_match_per(reads_list):
    match_percentages = dict.fromkeys(reads_list)
    for read in reads_list:
        matches = re.findall(r'(G|C)', read)
        matched_percent = len(matches)/len(read)
        match_percentages[read] = round(matched_percent*100, 2)

    return match_percentages
```

```
In [32]: strl = ['G and C', 'only G', 'double CC']

In [33]: str_match_per(strl)
Out[33]: {'G and C': 28.57, 'only G': 16.67, 'double CC': 22.22}
```